# IBOutlet error in viewcontroller swift 3

Tags: xcode, swift3, iboutlet

Whren i try to change backgorundcolor to anyview always return nil, but in another viewcontroller at the same storyboard works fine.

I cleaned the proyect and DereivedData.

```
@IBOutlet weak var testView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.testView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amroy.png)

Comment: The outlet is probably not connected to the storyboard.

Comment: the outlet is connected i think, I edited the question with an image, is something wrong?

Answer (score -2):

did you restarted Xcode?, because thats one of the things that I do when a problem like this appears, you could try with that, or even restarting your computer.